# Google Vision API Text extraction data accuracy (DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, vision-api

Using JAVA SDK for GCP Vision API for OCR (text extraction). Have moved to Feature **TEXT_DETECTION** to **DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION**. The image I have tested has the name “Mohan D”.

> - **TEXT_DETECTION**: I am getting a correct text, but not getting another    character
> - If I am using **DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION**, getting a name as “MOHAND (space is not coming)

Can you please suggest, whether I need to use any specific option to get more data accuracy

Answer (score 0):

The models used by **Cloud Vision API** service are always being improved in order to provide a better recognition accuracy; however, sometimes they get the characters wrong or even they don't recognize the characters themselves. Keep in mind these services are trained in a daily basis which means the recognition quality will increase accordingly.

Based on this, I think that the available workaround is to follow the [files format/size](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) and [language](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages) recommendations, as well as implement the `LanguageHints` property that is commonly used when the service has difficulties detecting the language included in the image and that may help you to increase the OCR results accuracy.

Comment: Yes, I am using LanguageHints property for betterment, are we able to train Vision API is there any option for the that (if yes please help).

I have processed 50,000 Identified proof in my account, If I have changed to client account all those train data will be applicable for their account or it will reside in mine.

Comment: The Vision API models are trained based on the daily usage in order to offer a better recognition quality and accuracy in a general basis. These improvements, are applied to all the request made to the service regardless of the client account used to perform the call, which means that training results will benefit to all the users that use the service. Please note that when you work with Vision API it is not possible to train you own models.

Comment: In case you want to train your own machine learning models, you can take a look on the [AutoML Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/) alternative; however, keep in mind this product is in Beta and currently has a limited features scope that is focused on classify your images according to your own defined labels.